# Is there an equivalent of mongo_find_one() in the new Mongo C driver

Tags: c, mongodb, mongo-c-driver

In the legacy Mongo C driver there was a a function `mongo_find_one`, which was used to find a single document in a MongoDB server.

```
MONGO_EXPORT int mongo_find_one( mongo *conn, const char *ns, const bson *query,const bson *fields, bson *out );
```

Is there a similar function in the new Mongo driver. I have been using the following documentation but was not able to find anything that is equivalent.

http://api.mongodb.org/c/1.2.0/

Comment: Is the link to 1.2.0 the old or the new version?  What was the old version you were using? What is the new version you are trying to use?

Comment: The link is for the new Driver. Which is C 1.2. The older version was 0.8. Here is the link to the repo for the old driver, https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver-legacy/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely an unsatisfying answer, but it does not appear there is a direct equivalent of the `mongo_find_one` function in version 1.2.0.

It should not however be particularly difficult to build a function with similar semantics using a cursor and taking only a single element from it and discarding the rest.